# Laravel 5.7: Get the value with greater than 0 with and condition

Tags: laravel-5.7

I have project and the technology were using is Laravel. I have table purchase_entries where my columns are: debit & credit amount etc.
I want to display only greater than to 0 of debit & credit.

If both 0.00 debit and credit, it wont display.

**Model**

```
public static function getPurchaseInvoiceItemsEntries($data)
{
    return DB::table('purchase_entries')
            ->where('purchase_id', $data)
            ->where('debit_amount','>=', 0.00 && 'credit_amount','>=', 0.00)
            //->where('credit_amount','>=', 0.00)
            ->get()->toArray();
}
```

Example:

```
       Debit            Credit
   1    5,000            0.00
   2    0.00             5,000
   3    0.00             0.00
```

3 will not display because its both 0.

Question: How can I fetch the debit & credit with greater than value to 0?

Comment: Have Tried `=` instead of  `>=`?

Comment: Your code/query seems on the right track.  What is the actual problem you have?

Comment: @SoheilRahmat I want to get > 0 values

Comment: sorry, I mean  try `>` instead of `>=`

Comment: Yes I already tried that @SoheilRahmat

Comment: I edited my post, I gave an example/scenario.

Comment: try `<>` OR `!=`

Comment: I already tried that too.